# swagger2 springboot whitelabel error page

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swaggerui

Подключаю сваггер по мануалу https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringFoxConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

помник

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

При обращении к http://localhost:8080/api-docs и http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html выдает

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Aug 17 16:48:52 MSK 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```